# Scraping IMDB's Top 250 List gives some results in foreign languages?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, imdb

I'm having my server grab this page to download the full list for a movie analysis I'm doing:
http://www.imdb.com/chart/top

But when it does a lot of the movie titles are appearing in another language. For example instead of saying The Shawshank Redemption it's giving me: Побег из Шоушенка

A simple file_get_contents in PHP is the fastest way to reproduce, though I'm using curl

Anyone have any ideas for what's going on, how to fix?

UPDATE: IMDB might be interpreting my server as being in another country for some strange reason. Is there any way to enforce it as being in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Use an user account and Set title display language at https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/siteprefs

Then automate the login process within your scraper and follow your normal process.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to deal with this in the Windows environment.  You may borrow the same idea for your server OS.

In Windows with a WebBrowser control, you can use menu View -> Encoding to select whatever language that shows the text properly, then when you grab the source page from the browser control, it will be in the correct coding.

You may find the IRobotSoft web scraper easy to use for your movie analysis, which runs in Windows platform only.